# Calculation of derived field in sql

Tags: sql

Taking Sql this quarter and not having any luck with the following question:

10. The height of players in feet (inches/12).  Include their name.  Hint: Calculation   or derived field.  Be sure to give the calculated field a column header.

We're learning the basic Select statment and didn't find any reference on how to make custom data at w3schools. I'm using Microsoft SQL server Management Express Here's my statment so far:

```
 select nameLast, nameFirst, height
 from Master
 where height    (I assume its something like 'Player_Height' = height/12)         
 order by nameLast, nameFirst, height
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
select nameLast, nameFirst, (height/12) as heightInInches
 from Master
 order by nameLast, nameFirst, height
```

Comment: kinda worked it gave me some null values though

Abbey Charlie NULL
Abbott Dan 5.91666666666667
Abbott Fred 5.83333333333333

Comment: nevermind I should have looked at height to figure out why I was getting  the null...missing values. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

If you need that result a lot, you might want to consider putting that into its own, computed column and persist it into your table. That way, it'll be up to date at all times, and you won't have to compute and re-compute it over and over and over again:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
   ADD HeightInFeet AS ROUND(Height / 12.0, 3) PERSISTED
```

With this, you can also round your result to e.g. 3 digits after the decimal point (or pick whatever makes sense to you). Each row in your table will now have a new column called `HeightInFeet`, always computed and always up to date, and you can query on it, you can return it in a SELECT - whatever you like to do! (you just can set a new value to it, since it's being computed by SQL Server itself, based on your `Height` column)